# PayPal Rest API Send Money from Personal Account to Personal Account

Tags: rest, paypal, currency, transfer

In my Windows-Desktop App I want allow to transfer money from one Personal-Account to another Personal Account. What is the best way to do that?

Using Payouts seems to requiere a business account for the money sender.

Answer (score 0):

In some countries, PayPal can facilitate fee-less "friends and family" payments from the PayPal balance or funding sources that don't charge significant fees, like bank accounts. If this is what you are looking for, all you can do is have the receiver of the payment create their own https://paypal.me link and direct the sender there, or if not using paypal.me then direct the sender to https://www.paypal.com/sendmoney to set up the transfer themselves.

Otherwise, only payments for "goods and services" are possible. There are many ways to set up a PayPal checkout between two accounts, and the receiver's account type is generally not of much importance although this may vary by country due to local legal regulations. A web page with a standard PayPal Checkout to pay another account can be [set up with HTML/JS](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/pay-another-account/), so you could have your app show a browser with such a page. Alternatively, the much older (~20 years) integration method that uses a full-page redirect is to create a link with this template:

> `https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_xclick&item_name=purpose%20of%20payment%20goes%20here&amount=100&currency_code=USD&business=emailusername@example.com`